# How to send array in http get request

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, rest, http-get

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int iIdx;
        int[] iData;
        bool[] bData;


        if (m_bRegister) // Read registers (4X references)
        {
            // read register (4X) data from slave
            if (adamTCP.Modbus().ReadHoldingRegs(m_iStart, m_iLength, out iData))
            {
                m_iCount++; // increment the reading counter
                txtStatus.Text = "Read registers " + m_iCount.ToString() + " times...";
                // update ListView

                label1.Text = HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value0=" + iData[0].ToString());
                label2.Text = HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value1=" + iData[1].ToString());
                label3.Text = HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value2=" + iData[2].ToString());
                label4.Text = HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value3=" + iData[3].ToString());
                label5.Text = HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value4=" + iData[4].ToString());

                for (iIdx = 0; iIdx < m_iLength; iIdx++)
                {
                    listViewModbusCur.Items[iIdx].SubItems[2].Text = iData[iIdx].ToString();            // show value in decimal
                    listViewModbusCur.Items[iIdx].SubItems[3].Text = iData[iIdx].ToString("X04");   // show value in hexdecimal

                }
```

How do i send array using httpget method? The code on top show that i'm sending data one by one. I need to send it in array and retrieve it back in api,php so that i could insert it into database in one row. currently, it's 1 data for 1 row.

Comment: convert array to json string then send it

Comment: mind showing some example. I'm a noob. Just learn programming. before only simple programming.

Answer (score 0):

you should passing 'value0' become just one querystring, ex : value[]

so the url will become

```
http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value[]="+ iData[0].ToString()"&value[]="+ iData[1].ToString() and etc what you want to send it "
```

or you should use `http_build_query` to the param array data

the code you show is php ??
the api maybe php but the code style more like .NET c#
correct me if im wrong.

//Update Response

```
string[] param = new string[(how many your counter param)]; 
param [0] = "test0"; 
param [1] = "test1"; 
param [2] = "test2"; 

in my example i give you 3
string sParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param) ;
HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value=" + sParams);
```

Comment: It's .NET C#. the api is in PHP. I tried writing code base on example you gave, but there is an error. "Only assignment, call, data ...." error.

Comment: string[] ss = new string[3];
ss[0] = "test0"; ss[1] = "test1"; ss[2] = "test2";
string sParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ss);
Uri uriCall = new Uri("http://localhost:56208/api/CreateGame/?opps=" + sParams);

Comment: HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value0=+ iData[0].ToString()&value1=+ iData[1].ToString()&value2=+ iData[2].ToString()&value3=+ iData[3].ToString()value4=+ iData[4].ToString()");

is it correct to write it like this?

Comment: you can do it like that too, but when your api read it, you gonna loop all query string with different param name. i update my answer you should try it.

Comment: It is intentional. I need to assign variable to every query string and apply it to calculation in my api. i just realise that in my query string, there is space between + and iData[]. Will it be a problem?

Comment: i recommend you to assign it to one variable then try to print it in order to debug and make sure the full url is correct,

Comment: try as you advised. only iData[0] is available and can be print. the rest only return 0. if i try to compile my application, it will show error. This code will be put in c# application by the way.

Comment: then its mean that your iData is not array OR the data output of iData its just one. you should define first where iData come from and loop through it to access every . example : Its same like when u access the index(n) array without even define the value of array(n)

Comment: iData is in the for loop. If i split iData to iData[0], iData[1], i can get the value.
for (iIdx = 0; iIdx < m_iLength; iIdx++)
{    listViewModbusCur.Items[iIdx].SubItems[2].Text = iData[iIdx].ToString();// show value in decimal
                        listViewModbusCur.Items[iIdx].SubItems[3].Text = iData[iIdx].ToString("X04");// show value in hexdecimal
}          label1.Text = HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1/misc/api1.php?value="+ iData[0].ToString()"&value1="+ iData[1].ToString()"&value2="+ iData[2].ToString()"&value3="+ iData[3].ToString()"&value4="+ iData[4].ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example to convert array to json in PHP

```
$arr=array(
    "varl1"=>1,
    "varl2"=>"example",
    "varl3"=>3,
 );

$json_arr=json_encode($arr);
```

Now you can send `$json_arr` 
and then you can decode it using `json_decode()`

Comment: This to be written in api.php or in c# coding?

Comment: this is the php  code, but if you need to send array using c# there is a similar trick in that too